# Having trouble getting phpmyadmin installed in Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions

Okay. I installed apache2 and php on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine. I copied the phpmyadmin files to `/var/www/phpmyadmin` so that the hierarchy looks like this:

```
-var (755)
   -www (144)
      -phpmyadmin (644)
         -index.php... etc. (644)
      -index.html (644)
```

The numbers in brackets are the permissions. What permissions should the phpmyadmin folder have? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then select apache2 as your server. Then whatever your first or default domain name it's domain.com/phpmyadmin

If you want to make it yourself, add an alias to a vhost file like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

then you'll need to remove the other alias from your apache2.conf file I believe.

Help File:
[phpMyAdmin](http://tinyurl.com/26qdd5f)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I had to manually add it to apache2.conf. Oh well.